# Collision Between 3d and 2D Objects AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d, collision-detection

I'm working on a augmented reality project using FLARtoolkit that need a collision between 3D between 2D objects in AS3. Im using papervision3d and away3d for 3d engine,
My 2d object is a circle and my 3d object is 3d model.

I have try different methods, but to no avail.
Those methods are

1. Using hitTestObject() on 3d model. Result = impilcit coercion
2. Using hitTestPoint() on 3d model. Result = cant get the correct model coordinate

I can't get the correct coordinate because the base of coordinate of my model is from marker, and the base of coordinate of my circle is from stage.

Oh yeah, and i try to make a 2D box with same position with my model for collision.
But the coordinate never get right.

Anyone can point me out ways to do collision between 2 different objects in different coordinate ?
Color tracking or anything ?
I appreciate any response, thank you.